# Understanding methods of existing objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am new to JavaScript, so I am reading some JavaScript code (for Google Earth Engine) and I got confused. I have some code that looks like the following pseudo code:

```
function function_0(some_existing_object_from_elsewhere, further_argument) {

    // What happened to these computing since they are not included in the returned dictionnary?
    some_existing_object_from_elsewhere = some_function(some_existing_object_from_elsewhere)
    further_argument = further_argument === undefined ? 0 : further_argument

    // return a dictionnary of function
    return {
      function_1: function_1,
      function_2: function_2
    }
    
    function function_1(args) {
        some Code
        return something
    }

    function function_2(args) {
        some Code

        // call to function_0. This is the most confusing. How the call to function_0 can be explained here? 
        return function_0(some_existing_object_from_elsewhere, further_argument)
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. What happens to the dictionary of functions returned here? Are these functions added to  `some_existing_object_from_elsewhere` as additional methods?
2. What happens to the computation before `return` since they are not included in the returned dictionary?
3. How does the call to `function_0` works inside `function_0` itself while `function_0` isn't really some sort-of recursive function? Then, what does `function_2` returns, the original `some_existing_object_from_elsewhere` or the processed `some_existing_object_from_elsewhere` as returned by `some_function(some_existing_object_from_elsewhere)`?

Overall, I am very confused. Any explanation and/or points to further reading would be helpful. Feel free to extend your explanations to other related aspects not captured in my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens to the dictionary of functions returned here? Are these functions added to some_existing_object_from_elsewhere as additional methods?

Not really, the object of returned functions only contains the functions defined in the object:

```
return {
    function_1: function_1,
    function_2: function_2
}
```

But the returned object is *linked* to the other functions not returned in that `function_1` and `function_2` have standard lexical scope of those other functions, because those other functions were defined in the same block that the returned functions were defined.

Essentially, what this means is that the object returned by `function_0` contains functions that can call *other functions*, without directly exposing those other functions to the caller of `function_0`.

> What happens to the computation before return since they are not included in the returned dictionary?

At the moment that `function_0` is called, nothing, really - the variables `some_existing_object_from_elsewhere` and `further_argument` simply become available to be used by `function_1` and `function_2`, if said functions in the retuned object are ever called.

> How does the call to function_0 works inside function_0 itself while function_0 isn't really some sort-of recursive function?

The `function_1` and `function_2`, since they're initially defined in the same block as `some_existing_object_from_elsewhere` and `further_argument`, *close over* those variables. See [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It means that those other variables become available for use by `function_1` and `function_2` until those functions become garbage-colleced.

> Then, what does function_2 returns, the original some_existing_object_from_elsewhere or the processed some_existing_object_from_elsewhere as returned by some_function(some_existing_object_from_elsewhere)?

The new objects. Here:

```
function function_0(some_existing_object_from_elsewhere, further_argument) {
    some_existing_object_from_elsewhere = some_function(some_existing_object_from_elsewhere)
    further_argument = further_argument === undefined ? 0 : further_argument
    return {
```

Both arguments get reassigned to new values, and then an object is returned which closes over all identifiers in scope. The identifiers reference the new values.

You may find it useful to browse the following links on the subject:

[https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36#:~:text=In%20other%20words%2C%20a%20closure,created%2C%20at%20function%20creation%20time.&text=The%20inner%20function%20will%20have,the%20outer%20function%20has%20returned](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36#:%7E:text=In%20other%20words%2C%20a%20closure,created%2C%20at%20function%20creation%20time.&text=The%20inner%20function%20will%20have,the%20outer%20function%20has%20returned).

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

https://blog.logrocket.com/how-javascript-closures-work-in-plain-english/

Answer (score 1):

Quick answers:

> 1. What happens to the dictionary of functions returned here? Are these functions added to `some_existing_object_from_elsewhere` as additional methods?

The function returns a new dictonary with only two keys, function_1 and function_2. `some_existing_object_from_elsewhere` is not involved in the the return or modified by the return.

> 2. What happens to the computation before return since they are not included in the returned dictionary?

Because these variables are used later in `function_2`, these variables become wrapped in a "closure", which saves these for use by function_2 later.
That means if you ran `function_0` twice with different inputs, and then ran the returned `function_2` for both of them, both executions of `function_2` would have different versions of `some_existing_object_from_elsewhere` and `further_argument`.
Closures can take some time to understand so I recommend looking up further resources on this.

> 3. How does the call to function_0 works inside function_0 itself while function_0 isn't really some sort-of recursive function?

The key here is that `function_0` is not being called inside `function_0`, it's being called inside the new function `function_2` which is returned to the calling scope, and so the calling scope is allowed to run it whenever it feels like it.
Not that there's anything preventing recursive functions in JS.

> Then, what does function_2 returns, the original some_existing_object_from_elsewhere or the processed some_existing_object_from_elsewhere as returned by some_function(some_existing_object_from_elsewhere)?

`function_2` runs `function_0` and returns the output of that run of that function. So it will also return a new dictionary with new versions of `function_1` and `function_2`.
In your example, it seems like `function_2` doesn't really do anything, so I'm guessing in Google Earth Engine there's some important modification to the arguments

Comment: I wish I can accept both answers, so I accept the first to come in. Otherwise, you have both clearly explained the problem. Thanks!